# Cancel alarm notification

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-pendingintent, android-alarms

I'm trying to cancel a alarm notification, but although i cancel it, at the given time the notification plays no mather its disabled or not.

So can someone help me cancel specific notification?

I set a repeating notification like this:

```
public static void setRepeatingAlarm(String time, int alarmID, String title) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(a, TimeAlarm.class);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.CALC_MSG, title);
        Log.v("--", title + " | " + time);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(a, alarmID,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        String timeArr[] = time.split(":");
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.valueOf(timeArr[0]));
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.valueOf(timeArr[1]));
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        if (cal.getTimeInMillis() < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
        }
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000), pendingIntent);
    }
```

And I'm trying to cancel it like this:

```
public static void cancelNotification(String time, int alarmID, String title) {
        Intent i = new Intent(a, TimeAlarm.class);
        i.putExtra(Constants.CALC_MSG, title);
        PendingIntent p = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(a, alarmID, i, 0);
        am.cancel(p);
        p.cancel();
    }
```

And here is my alarm service class:

```
public class TimeAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

    NotificationManager nm;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        nm = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm.cancelAll();
        CharSequence from = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
        CharSequence message = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.CALC_MSG)
                .toUpperCase();
        int iconRes = R.drawable.ic_stat_notf_icon;
        int notificationID = intent.getIntExtra(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Main.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);

        Notification notif = new Notification(iconRes, message,
                System.currentTimeMillis());
        notif.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(
                context.getPackageName(), context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        notif.audioStreamType = AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION;
        notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, contentIntent);
        notif.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://"
                + context.getPackageName() + "/"
                + prefs.getInt(Constants.NOTIF_SOUND, R.raw.al_affassi_full));

        nm.notify(notificationID, notif);
        // r.play();

    }
}
```

Comment: the pending intents to set and cancel the alarm have to be equal. Be sure You give the same alarmId. I think also You have to set the same flag: PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static void stopAlarm(Context context) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent your_intent = new Intent(...);
        PendingIntent your_pending_intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, your_intent, 0);
        alarmManager.cancel(your_pending_intent);
    }
```

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: Can you please help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51542099/cant-stop-the-ringing-alarm-from-another-activity#51542099 @Alejandro Martínez Martínez

Answer (score 2):

Pending intent should be like this

```
public static void cancelNotification(String time, int alarmID, String title) {
    Intent i = new Intent(a, TimeAlarm.class);
    i.putExtra(Constants.CALC_MSG, title);
    PendingIntent p = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(a, alarmID, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    am.cancel(p);
    p.cancel();
}
```